# Counting sub-document matches in a mongo document

Tags: mongodb, counting

I have a failry simple structure for my documents:

```
{regId: 1, data: {[{val: 123456}, {val: 324234}, {val: 4353453}, .......]}}
```

The data element array may contain between 30 and 60 sub-documents and currently the collection has ~53000 documents, but will grow much larger.

Given an array of vals, INPUT, [11563012,11563011,82867218,83866648, ....], 
I want to return documents that have at least 3 matching data.val.  Currently, I query using an $in modifier and a $where clause that calls a js 
function  (countMatches).  The $in modifier returns any document that contains at least one item for IMPUT and the $where function iterates through each document.date, counting matches in INPUT and only returns documents above the threshold:

```
db.foo.find({"data.val": {$in: [11563012,11563011,82867218,83866648,.......]}, $where: "countMatches(this.data, [11563012,11563011,82867218,83866648,......])>=3"}).count();
```

Similar questions (http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/fa291575fd47c010) seem to indicate that the only way to count matchs in "sub-documents" is 
either with a js function in a $where clause or with a group() aggregate function.

My question then is, is there a better method for counting "hits" in a sub-document?  This is semantically similar to finding "tagged" documents, i.e. return the documents that have the most matching tags of [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4,.....]

Comment: Can I ask why do your documents look like that? It should be simply `{regId: 1, data: [123456, 324234, 4353453]}`

Comment: I simplified the structure for the post; each of the sub-documents actually has more elements that are not involved with the query

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$where`, there is no better way to do this.

Be aware that if your `$in` filter returns a large portion of the collection you won't be able to scale with this solution... (and it's going to be tough to scale with any other solution)